# where can i get app back that opens a tab for all my apps?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

My smartphone was open in my pocket and the application that opens the tab for my all apps disappeared. Now i can open apps that are not on the home screen just through the play store.

phone sony xperia xz2 compact, android pie 9

[image: not my phone but to make it easier to explain what i am missing i put red circle around it.]

Comment: Usually, there's always a way to open the app menu from the home screen (e.g. by dragging from the bottom of the screen). However, without much information, it's almost impossible to guess the cause. At the very least, could you provide the phone model, the Android version, and whether you're using 3rd-party launcher or not? Additionally, a screenshot of the problem might help.

Comment: Not my phone but I drew a red circle around what's missing.  Can I get that somewhere back? Without it i can't find any others means to launch my apps tha play store. (phone sony xperia xz2 compact, android pie 9)

Comment: thanks very much Andrew T. looks like i can open that tab by dragging from the bottom of the screen.